# Import different file location STYLUS

Tags: meteor, stylus

I have file stucture like this

```
client
  stylesheet
    main.import.styl
  template
    a
      a.styl
    b
      b.styl
```

And I try to import `main.import.styl` in `a.styl` and `b.styl` like this

`@import main.import`

(also I try other options like `/main.import`, `./...`, and more) in result I have `failed to locate @import main.import.styl`

But if I put `a` and `b` files in `stylesheet` all works fine

I use [meteor stylus](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/stylus)

My poblem in simple way: 
files do not see each other in different folders

```
folder1
  a.import.styl
folder2
  b.styl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax would be :

```
@import '{}/client/stylesheet/main.import.styl'
```

Please refer to the [stylus package docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/stylus#cross-packages-imports) for additional information.